# Plotting graph using gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

```
htmlResponseBytes 39842 397888
cssResponseBytes 109265 108988
imageResponseBytes 205179 206662
javascriptResponseBytes 468573 476888
otherResponseBytes 4326 4378
```

I want to plot Bar graph this data using `gnuplot`. 1st column should be present on x-axis, 2nd and 3rd column should be plotted using bar chart. 2nd column should have legend today and 3rd column should have legend yesterday. Also the values should be present on top of each bar.

I have tried this

```
   reset
   dx=5.
   n=2
   total_box_width_relative=0.75
   gap_width_relative=0.1
   d_width=(gap_width_relative+total_box_width_relative)*dx/2.
   reset
   set term png truecolor
   set output "profit.png"
   set xlabel "Year"
   set ylabel "Profit(Million Dollars)"
   set grid
   set boxwidth total_box_width_relative/n relative
   set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
   plot "profit.dat" u 1:2 w boxes lc rgb"green" notitle,\
   "profit.dat" u ($1+d_width):3 w boxes lc rgb"red" notitle
```

[Copied this code from here, works fine for his data file but doesn't work for mine data file pasted at the top](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.in/2011/09/plot-histograms-using-boxes.html?showComment=1344329138033#c5515227792059446213)

Comment: Please see the [faq] and [ask] for a guide to asking good questions. Specifically, your question lacks information about a _specific_ programming problem: what have you tried? How was the result different from what you expected?

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to add this information?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
set style data histogram 
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set xtics rotate by 90
set style fill solid
plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) lc rgb "blue", \
     '' using 3
```